# Virtuoso ISQL data import can't stat file

Tags: file-access, virtuoso

In `isql-vt` (the Ubuntu name for Virtuoso's `isql`), I am trying to import a test .ttl file, but get the error "Can't stat file":

```
SQL> DB.DBA.TTLP(file_to_string_output('./scratch/ttl/granule.ttl'),'','http://origin.mytest.org/');

*** Error 42000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]FA112: Can't stat file './scratch/ttl/granule.ttl', error (2) : No such file or directory
```

However, the file is definitely there; I can even `cat` it:

```
SQL> !cat ./scratch/ttl/granule.ttl;
@prefix datacite: <http://purl.org/spar/datacite/> .
@prefix prov: <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#> .
<http://0.0.0.0:3000/granule/MOD09.A2016278.0110.006.2016279074214.hdf>
   datacite:identifier "MOD09.A2016278.0110.006.2016279074214.hdf";
   prov:wasGeneratedBy <http://0.0.0.0:3000/run/MODAPS_456056327>;
   a prov:entity .

SQL>
```

Why is the `DB.DBA.TTLP` command saying it can't stat it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trying to use the full path gave a *much* better error message:

```
SQL> DB.DBA.TTLP(file_to_string_output('/home/ubuntu/Origin/scratch/ttl/granule.ttl'),'','http://origin.nasa.gov/');

*** Error 42000: [Virtuoso Driver][Virtuoso Server]FA003: Access to 
'/home/ubuntu/Origin/scratch/ttl/granule.ttl' is denied due to access control in ini file
```

So, the solution was to add the path in `/etc/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/virtuoso.ini`, eg:

```
...
DirsAllowed  = ., /usr/share/virtuoso-opensource-6.1/vad, /home/ubuntu/Origin
...
```

and restart virtuoso for the change to take effect.

Comment: I notice you're apparently running the very old Virtuoso 6.1.  [Virtuoso 7.2.4](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews) is recommended for all users. [This answer](http://serverfault.com/a/678864/245036) may help you get there.